# react jsx inline if else altering style value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know how to use different class in jsx using if else short hand in jxs, but how can I do that too with style?

says I have a loop where I need to check whether a property is present, if yes add margin top 10 to a div?

```
<div style={{marginTop:10}} />
```

Comment: <div style={ property ? {marginTop:10} : {}} />

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With inline if-else:

```
<div style={isMarginNeeded ? {marginTop:10} : {}} />
```

You can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 11):

You can do it like this:

```
<div style={present ? {marginTop:10} : {}} />
```

or like this:

```
<div style={{marginTop: present ? 10 : 0 }} />
```

or more complicated style with spread operator:

```
<div style={{
  marginLeft:10,
  ...( present ? {marginTop:10} : {} ),
}} />
```